# Dynamic Video Player Will Not Release Focus

Tags: c#, focus, dynamic-controls

Hi Everyone i Know By Default Labels and Picture Box cannot Have Focus, i Design a Method on the Form Key down to Move these Controls About with the arrow buttons

When i Make a Dynamic Video Player Control, i Can No longer move these controls nor does the form appear to gain focus anymore

I Have Tried This.Focus after making the video player, is there anything anyone can think of that maybe could keep focus on the form permanent

If Example Code is Need i will copy, but the code itself appears to be fine the video player just keeps the focus

Form 1 Keydown

```
        if (SenderS == "Label")
        {
            // Label b = sender as Label;
            Label b = (Label)Controls[ControlID];
            int x = b.Location.X;
            int y = b.Location.Y;

            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right) x += 1;
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left) x -= 1;
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up) y -= 1;
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down) y += 1;

            b.Location = new Point(x, y);
        }
```

Label Mouse Down

```
        SenderS = "Label";
        Label b=sender as Label;

        ControlID = b.Name;
```

This Code Works fine but when a video is added to the form i can no longer use it 
i assume because the form no longer accepts the keydown event

Comment: and the code for what you are doing is.......??

Comment: @terrybozzio i add example code of what i am doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presented as general purpose,You first need to override the IsInputKey method:

```
        private void YourControl_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            //your logic here
        }

        protected override bool IsInputKey(System.Windows.Forms.Keys keyData)
        {
            switch (keyData)
            {
                case Keys.Right:
                case Keys.Left:
                case Keys.Up:
                case Keys.Down:
                    return true;
            }
            return base.IsInputKey(keyData);
        }
```

Or override the ProcessCmdKey method.

Comment: This Fixed my issue i will mark it as correct, Although i Do Not Understand Why Would you mind explaining what it does?

Comment: its saying to treat those keys as input,because in the implementation those keys are left out from the keydown event(very basicaly speaking).

Comment: Thanks For The Help and the information i learn something new every day ^^